# How do I calculate the age of the user in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I'm trying to write a function in Powershell where I calculate the age of the user based on the birthdate. So it should probably be currentdate - birthdate and put the difference in years. I'm getting stuck however, on the formating of these dates because the user has to input their birthdate.

```
Function getAge ($birthDate)
{
    $currentDate = Get-Date
    $age = $currentDate - $birtDate
    Write-Host "Your age is $age"
}
getAge 24-01-1991
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is almost there, except for the fact that it creates and returns a TimeSpan object with the difference between the current and the given date.

Try

```
function Get-Age {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [datetime]$birthDate
    ) 
    $currentDate = Get-Date
    $age = $currentDate - $birthDate

    # use the ticks property from the resulting TimeSpan object to 
    # create a new datetime object. From that, take the Year and subtract 1
    ([datetime]::new($age.Ticks)).Year - 1
}

# make sure the BirthDate parameter is a valid DateTime object
Get-Age ([datetime]::ParseExact('24-01-1991', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the input parameter `$birthDate`, currently a *string*, to a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) object, for that you can use the [`ParseExact(..)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider)). Then you need to decide which type of date format your function will accept, I have added a [ValidatePattern attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatepattern-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) to the function so that currently only accepts the pattern shown in your question, this however can be updated so that the function takes more than one format (`ParseExact(..)` can also parse multiple formats). Lastly, you're correct with **Current Date - Birth Date**, this will get us a [`TimeSpan` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) which has a `.Days` property, we can use the value of the property and divide it by the number of days in a year to obtain the user's age.

```
function getAge {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [ValidatePattern('^(\d{2}-){2}\d{4}$')]
    [string]$birthDate
)

    $parsedDate = [datetime]::ParseExact(
        $birthDate,
        'dd-MM-yyyy',
        [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    )

    [int] $age = ([datetime]::Now - $parsedDate).Days / 365
    Write-Host "Your age is $age"
}

getAge 24-01-1991
```